# Sum Columns with Same ID

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 datatables, i merged them. After merged, I want to show them in datagrid, However If there is same 'id' columns should be sum and group.

Example;
Currently it looks like this

[image]

What i want is sum them if 'realid' column is same like below;

[image]

I currently did below code and at the end i bind it to datagrid.

What should i do after that ?

```
        DataTable dtNewTable = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtCurtable = new DataTable();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Add columns
            DataColumn column2 = new DataColumn("counts", typeof(System.Int32));
            DataColumn column3 = new DataColumn("realid", typeof(string));
            dtNewTable.Columns.Add(column2);
            dtNewTable.Columns.Add(column3);


            dtCurtable = dtNewTable.Copy();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataRow row;
            Random r = new Random();

            dtNewTable.Clear();


            for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
            {
                row = dtNewTable.NewRow();
                row["counts"] = r.Next(10,40) ;
                row["realid"] = i + " id";
                dtNewTable.Rows.Add(row);

            }

            dtCurtable.Merge(dtNewTable);
            dataGrid1.DataSource = dtCurtable;

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Linq here like

```
var dt1 = dtCurtable.AsEnumerable()
              .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("realid"))
              .Select(g =>
              {
              DataRow row = dtCurtable.NewRow();
              row["realid"] = g.Key;
              row["Count"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("counts"));


              return row;
          }).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: what's the 'dt' in here DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

Comment: I get datetime from database; However this throws na error ; row2["SAMPLE_TIME"] = g.Select(h => h.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME"));

Comment: @johntrue NO you can't do that since that column is not part of `group by`. Post this issue separably in a question with all releavent information